# Facebook Login using acess token and offline post through webapp

Tags: javascript, .net, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have an access token, but how do I login via access token using JavaScript?

I want to post on my wall even when I am not logged in, using my access token, so I only click a button to post on wall and not need to login again and again.

```
       if (response.status === 'connected') {
            console.log(response.authResponse.accessToken); 
       }
```

How do I process further and login via access token?

Comment: Try to add the token to the API call `FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', {message: 'Hello, world!', access_token: YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN});`

Comment: but  how to resolve this
 "Object {authResponse: undefined, status: "unknown"}" 
after using token..

Comment: javascript function needed to convert short term token to long term

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the access token is, but I am aware of two ways to share to Facebook from a web application:

1. Share Button - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button
2. Web API - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/web

The Web API has a javascript SDK you can use as well.